# SVG image not load as par view in Fabric 2.3 version

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

SVG image Save and loadJson preview display large or small also after i scaling it is display large or small.

please check I have created jsfiddle link: 
   http://jsfiddle.net/bw1kj4oh/8/

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(document.getElementById('test').outerHTML, function (objects, options) {
    obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas.add(obj);
});

document.getElementById('json').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var json = canvas.toJSON();
    canvas.clear();

    canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function () {
        canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.getObjects()[0]);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the number of fraction digits

```
fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 10;
```

Check here:http://jsfiddle.net/9wsjgbuz/

Comment: Please validate the answer then

Comment: Hello Marius, 10  value fixed ? 10 value is working any type of SVG ?

Comment: 10 is a decent value.. you had there some values like 2.123456. the default value of  `fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS` was 2. So the saved value before this changed was 2.12

Comment: Thank you, I understand :-)